# What is the difference between inner, internal, and interior conflict?

Tags: vocabulary, writing

What is the difference between inner, internal, and interior conflict?

Can we use the term "interior"? If no, why?

Comment: Usually you want to include your question in the body of the question, not just in the title.

Comment: Hello Sophie. On this website, a question is off-topic if it has more than one question, or if it asks something that a dictionary can answer. Please choose just one question to ask, and show us what you've found by looking up these words in a good dictionary, like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com)

Answer (score 0):

These words are very nearly the same in meaning. Mostly it's a matter of what they are most often used for. You can correctly use any of them.

When referring to the processes of the mind, usually that will be inner. As for example [The Inner Life of Cats](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0316262900).

Internal is not wrong. Usually internal will be used to refer to the physical insides of something, such as a doctor of internal medicine.

Also, interior is not wrong. Usually interior will refer to the insides of some region well away from the boundary. As, for example, the [Interior of British Columbia](https://pcnjobsbc.ca/?da_image=258).

So if you were referring to somebody having a difficult time making up their mind, that would probably be an inner conflict. If they were suffering from digestive upset that would be an internal conflict. And if they were having difficulty climbing a mountain in the Canadian Rockies that might be an interior conflict.